# White hover boxes on nav menu

Tags: css, nav

my website: http://reckless-gaming.com/aT/
is a gaming website.

but as you hover over the nav menu at the top, for the first time you hover, a white box appears, then goes away. All my nav CSS coding is correct, at least I hope.

Comment: I suspect that's a pause between the browser loading the background-image and applying it to the element.

Answer (score 2):

### The reason why there's a white box on hover

The reason why that is happening is because the hover images aren't loaded yet, therefore the browser loads them when you hover over them, so your CSS is fine. :)

### Solution 1: Use a jQuery Plugin

Consider using this [preloading jQuery plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/) to preload the images. Define it before your CSS file. It automatically preloads all the images in the CSS, so all you need to do is call `$.preloadCssImages();`. Here's an example of what you would do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/preloadCssImages.jQuery_v5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.preloadCssImages();
}); 
</script>
<link href="_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can download that plugin [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/preloadImages/scripts/preloadCssImages.jQuery_v5.js).

### Solution 2: Load hover images in a hidden div

Another way is to just preload them the HTML way by putting all the images into a hidden `<div>`:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<img src="hoverImage1.jpg" />
<img src="hoverImage2.jpg" />
<img src="hoverImage3.jpg" />
 etc..
</div>
```

Then they would already be loaded and that white "box" wouldn't show. Either way works; whatever is best for you!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try preloading your navigation images.  Or better yet - use CSS to apply the underline, rather than a separate image.